# if statement, print additional column in python

Tags: python, loops, csv, if-statement

i am new to pythin and trying to work out an if statement for some data being collected.

```
import grovepi
import time
import datetime
import grovelcd
#headerline
print ("Time,Noise (db),Light (lux),Temperature (C),Humidity (rH)")
```

here i have the already existing header lines for when they are printed into a csv file.I want another displaying the information i outline below.

```
while True:
  timestamp=time.time()
  #read from a analog sensor on input 1
  d= grovepi.analogRead(1)
  #read from an analog sensor on input 2
  a= grovepi.analogRead(2)
  #read from an digital sensor on input 3
  (t,h)=grovepi.dht(3,0)
```

above is the reading of each sensor

```
print ("%f,%d,%d,%f,%f"%(timestamp,d,a,t,h))
```

What i would like is an additional value, i am having issues getting an if statement to take the value and determine if it matches what i want. All these should be number values.

the idea i have is

```
if t > 35:
  print("Warning")
if h > 50:
  print("Warning")
if n > 75:
  print("Warning")
else:
  print("OK")
```

Essentially what i have looks like this output:

```
Noise  Light   Temperature   Humidity
85      500        34           76
```

What im trying to achieve is this:

```
Noise  Light   Temperature   Humidity  Note
85      500        34           76      OK
```

Any help appreciated, i dont know python very well unfortunately.

Comment: First, there is no built-in `sprint()`. Does this function come from another module? Second, the `else` in the `if` statement refers only to the last `if`. OK will be printed only if `n<=75`, regardless of the values of `t` and `h`. If you want to print OK when there are no warnings, you need to rewrite the last block of code.

Comment: I have changed the sprint, should be print i think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to print an extra column, like "1234567890,34.3,51.2,70.3,Warning" then you can do it with a simple boolean variable, like this:

```
while True:
    ...
    warning = t > 35 or h > 50 or n > 75
    print ("%f,%d,%d,%f,%f,%s" % (
        timestamp, d, a, t, h, "Warning" if warning else "OK"
    ))
```

Above, I've defined `warning` as a boolean condition, and used if for the inline `if` operator to print either "Warning" or "OK".

If you need extra flexibility you can assign to a string variable:

```
while True:
    ...
    # Note, only message for the first matching condition would display
    if t > 35:
        message = "Warning: T"
    elif h > 50:
        message = "Warning: H"
    elif n > 75:
        message = "Warning: N"
    else:
        message = "OK"
    print ("%f,%d,%d,%f,%f,%s" % (timestamp, d, a, t, h, message))
```

And if you need to display multiple messages, you can collect a list, like this:

```
while True:
    ...
    warnings = []
    if t > 35:
        warnings.append("WarnT")
    if h > 50:
        warnings.append("WarnH")
    ...
    status = " ".join(warnings) if warnings else "OK"
    print ("%f,%d,%d,%f,%f,%s" % (timestamp, d, a, t, h, status))
```

This would collect all warnings in a list (so it would be like `["WarnT", "WarnH"]`), then if the list is not empty join with spaces (`" ".join(warnings)`) so it'll be "WarnT WarnH", and otherwise use "OK" as the message. Tune the output as you feel appropriate.

Hope this helps.

(BTW, you may consider using something like `%0.2f` instead of `%f` if you want a fixed number of digits. I believe you'd probably want to round to a sane precision, e.g. "59.03" instead of something like "59.031045032")

Comment: Just tried it out, works great thanks. Good to know about the more flexible options too, very helpful.

Comment: Great. Also, just wanted to point out that you don't need parentheses in `t, h = grovepi.dht(3, 0)`, around `t, h`. Having parentheses there isn't a mistake - just that they're unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks, anything to make it more tidy is great. Thanks for the help, early days of python for me but i will get there!